# How to forced refresh page with IE?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I've done an online application (php), and there is a button which opens a modal window (bootstrap). With firefox I've no problem. But with Internet Explorer (I know but all the clients work with Internet Explorer), the form doesn't reload.
I explain :
When I submit the form, I get all the info and put them in a database. The webpage is refreshed. So with firefox when I click on the button, the form opens and the infos are written. But with IE, it's still the same form, the new information are not written.
I know that's an issue with Internet Explorer and an option with the cache. 
So I found on Google this :

```
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

And also this :

```
<meta name="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

But it's still not working on Internet Explorer. The problem is I don't know which option cache my clients have...

Comment: Are you submitting your form with AJAX? If you are posting data your web page should be refreshing no matter what. Have you tried including a header redirect to the same page after your PHP submit code has ran?

Comment: Not with AJAX. I'm posting data , the page refreshs but the form is still the same, the previously data are not written in the form. And if I check the option in IE to check if a new page exists at each refresh, then all work but I don't know what option will be checked in the client's Internet Explorer...

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Make sure `Cache-Control: no-cache header` is set and see if that helps

Comment: It's set...And still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add with javascript `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.website.com/page.html">` (in head) when submitting the form